# Tips/Tricks for beginners in Analysis and Recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I'm taking my first course in analysis this semester and I find it too hard/ unapproachable although we have not even covered a lot of syllabus as of yet.

So far, we have done elementary set theory, functions, relations, cardinalities and then moved on to sequences, convergence, monotone sequences, cauchy sequences and limsup and liminf.

I was good(read: not too bad) at all the stuff covered up until we started sequences. I don't know how to study for it. I cover all the lectures and try to understand/grasp the proofs done there; still, I feel it doesn't help a lot. Sometimes, the proofs are  too difficult to grasp and sometimes, faced with a theorem to proof, I find it hard to start constructing a proof.

Are there any tips/tricks to think a certain way for the aforementioned topics starting from sequences? Also, how does one get better? Is there anything that can be done to improve your analysis-skills?

Thank you.

Comment: It helped me to think of a sequence as like an infinite deck of cards, each card has a real number on it. It's not some magical trick that makes everything make sense but it made things more concrete for me. For example when talking about limits ($\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$), the idea of $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$ meant that there was some card in the deck ($x_N$) such that all the cards after that would be within $\epsilon$ of $L$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes it better, but things take a big leap when we move from this basic definition to more complex ideas/theorems.

Comment: yes, it doesn't immediately clarify things but it helps visualization a bit in my opinion. it helped me with lim inf and lim sup especially.

Comment: Can you let me know what books or any helpful online-available notes/lectures you consulted to ensure you fully grasped  the concepts and ultimately, aced the course?

Comment: I used whatever book was assigned for the course which I can't remember now but it wasn't anything special. as for online resources, the place you are at is already the best one. when it comes to things with sequences sometimes things can be counterintuitive, it helps to ask/think about counter examples and understand why we have to define things a certain way. when you see a weird counter example you can then understand, "oh, we have to define it this way because there are ugly sequences like xxx that we want to exclude/include", that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to find an example verifying the statement of the Theorem; many counterexamples in order to understand concretely how hypotheses are fundamental for giving the Theorem and, then, you can study the proof verifying where the hypotheses have been used. I think that this is the better way to study math.

Comment: I feel like most of the textbooks assume that the reader knows a lot of stuff and jump 2-3 steps ahead, missing out so much in between that someone who has just begun to do analysis is unable to understand the proof.